# Grouping by another column after tables are joined

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a query to return some data back from multiple tables. I've anonymized the data, but you should still be able to understand the problem

```
select distinct device.gamertag, count(network.trophies) as `Trophies`, person from people
inner join device on people.gamertag=device.gamertag
inner join network on device.consoledevicename=network.consoledevicename
group by device.gamertag order by count(network.trophies) desc
```

I'm left with a results that looks something like this

| Gamertag | Trophies | Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TheGreatJuan | 45 | Juan |
| Juan46 | 155 | Juan |
| NewGT5555 | 3 | Lucas |
| TheGreatJuan2 | 77 | Juan |
| GuestAccount | 1 | Guest |

My tables looks like this:

- Person

| Gamertag | Person |
| --- | --- |
| TheGreatJuan | Juan |
| Juan46 | Juan |
| NewGT5555 | Lucas |
| TheGreatJuan2 | Juan |
| GuestAccount | Guest |

- Device

| gamertag | consoledevicename |
| --- | --- |
| TheGreatJuan | JuansPS4 |
| Juan46 | JuanPS5 |
| NewGT5555 | LucasXbox |
| TheGreatJuan2 | JuanPS4 |
| GuestAccount | LucasXbox360 |

- Network

| trophies | consoledevicename |
| --- | --- |
| MGS2 | JuansPS4 |
| MGS2 | JuanPS4 |
| MGS3 | JuanPS4 |
| SAMPL5 | LucasXbox |
| RED6 | JuanPS5 |
| BLU8 | LucasXbox360 |

I want to be able to take my existing query and aggregate how many trophies a person has on all their accounts. For the sake of this questions, please assume that a person can have 2 or more trophies of the same kind, which is why they need filtered out.

My desired results looks like:

| Name | Trophies |
| --- | --- |
| Juan | 277 |
| Lucas | 3 |
| Guest | 1 |

Thanks in the advance!

Comment: Sample input data for all tables would be really helpful here.

Comment: Added some sample tables for more context

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter out duplicate combinations of `gamertag` and `trophies` before you join to `Person` and group by `person` and not by `gamertag` and :

```
SELECT p.person, COUNT(t.trophies) total_trophies
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT d.gamertag, n.trophies
  FROM Device d INNER JOIN Network n 
  ON d.consoledevicename = n.consoledevicename
) t ON t.gamertag = p.gamertag
GROUP BY p.person 
ORDER BY total_trophies DESC
```

If you want to include in the results persons who don't belong to any device or don't have any trophies you should change the `INNER` joins to `LEFT` joins.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=103ccbfd1539f03a71a582ccacfb3eff).
Results (for your sample data):

| person | total_trophies |
| --- | --- |
| Juan | 4 |
| Guest | 1 |
| Lucas | 1 |

Comment: this is very close -- and i might be able to build off this. But there are cases where the same trophyname will appear more than once. Using distinct here removes those occurrences. What i want to omit is areas where the combination of the gamertag, trophy, and person are duplicated.

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the aggregation:

```
select p.person, count(*) as Trophies
from people p join
     device d
     on p.gamertag = d.gamertag join
     network n
     on d.consoledevicename = n.consoledevicename
group by p.person
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want one row per person, then that should be the only key in the `GROUP BY`.

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and read.

Answer (score -1):

If your first query returns the first table, then

```
select 
  device.gamertag, 
  sum(network.trophies), 
  person 
from people
inner join device on people.gamertag=device.gamertag
inner join network on device.consoledevicename=network.consoledevicename
group by device.person
order by count(network.trophies) desc
```

should return the second table.
Simply sum the trophies and group by device.person.

Comment: You forgot to change the select list.

Comment: This solution ignore the fact that there are duplicates, and i need to retrieve distinct entries